# SharedPreference not recreating menu

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to use SharedPreferences to store a preference, then change the default checked state of the menu item based on the SharedPreference. But it does not seem to be working. The menu choice stays until the app is closed. When I reload the app, the setting is back to the default, instead of the new SharedPreference setting.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

boolean prefs = true;
String FILENAME = "settings";
String string;

public static final String LOG_TAG = "dbryant423";
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "settings";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "prefs value: " +prefs);

 }

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String preference = settings.getString("preference", string);
    if (preference == "us")
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_us).setChecked(true);
    else if (preference == "metric")
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_metric).setChecked(true);
    return true; 
}

// called when an item is selected
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) { // decide which MenuItem was pressed based on it's id
    case R.id.menu_us:
            menuUS();

    case R.id.menu_metric:
            menuMetric();

    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    if (prefs == true)
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_us).setChecked(true);
    else if (prefs == false)
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_metric).setChecked(true);
    return true;
}

public void menuUS() {
    prefs = true;
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("preference", "us");
    editor.commit();
}

public void menuMetric() {
    prefs = false;
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("preference", "metric");
    editor.commit();
}

public void calculateCylinder(View v) {
    Intent calculateCylinderUS = new Intent(this, CalculateCylinder.class);
    Intent calculateCylinderMetric = new Intent(this, CalculateCylinderMetric.class);
     Log.v(LOG_TAG, "prefs value: " +prefs);
    if (prefs == true)
        startActivity(calculateCylinderUS);
    else if (prefs == false)
        startActivity(calculateCylinderMetric);
}
```

Comment: Ram kiran thanks for the tag edit. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that `onPrepareOptionsMenu` gets called just before the menu is displayed to the user.
Looking at your code you are calling `setChecked(true)` on `R.id.menu_us` and `R.id.menu_metric` based on local variable `prefs` whose value will **always** be `true` whenever the activity is created. So in order to persist these states we must update menu-items based on preference values and not based on values of local variable.

I think you'd rather modify your `onPrepareOptionsMenu`and `onCreateOptionsMenu` functions as below and give it a try:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true; 
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String preference = settings.getString("preference", string);
    if (preference == "us")
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_us).setChecked(true);
    else if (preference == "metric")
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_metric).setChecked(true);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: ok, when I changed my code to reflect that, it still starts in the default of "us", but now, no matter which one I choose, it switches to "metric", and I can't change it back. Also, "prefs" isn't a local variable, it's declared much earlier right under the `public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    
 boolean prefs = true;
 String FILENAME = "settings";
 String string;` that is what makes the changes persistent until it is closed and restarted.

Comment: The answer helped with part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't compare string variables by `==` sign

here

```
if (preference == "us")
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_us).setChecked(true);
    else if (preference == "metric")
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_metric).setChecked(true);
```

instead use `.equals()`

```
if (preference.equals("us"))
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_us).setChecked(true);
    else if (preference.equals("metric"))
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_metric).setChecked(true);
```

Comment: The answer helped with part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I used a little bit from both answers, and I found some missing pieces myself. One of the main problems I figured out, is that I did not have a "break;" in my switch statement, and it was running both cases, no matter which one I selected. The other final fix was instead of calling

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String preference = settings.getString("preference", string);
    if (preference.equals("us"))
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_us).setChecked(true);
    else if (preference.equals("metric"))
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_metric).setChecked(true);
    return true; 

}
```

in which my if/else if statements are trying to modify the setChecked attribute, I realized all I needed to do was modify the value of "prefs" instead in the onCreateOptionsMenu. like so:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String preference = settings.getString("preference", string);
    if (preference.equals("us"))
        prefs = true;
    else if (preference.equals("metric"))
        prefs = false;
    return true; 

}
```

The onPrepareOptionsMenu still needs the "setChecked" in order to switch which choice has been selected.
here is the updated working code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

boolean prefs = true;
String FILENAME = "settings";
String string;

public static final String LOG_TAG = "dbryant423";
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "settings";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "prefs value onCreate: " +prefs);

 }

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String preference = settings.getString("preference", string);
    if (preference.equals("us"))
        prefs = true;
    else if (preference.equals("metric"))
        prefs=false;
    return true; 

}

// called when an item is selected
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) { // decide which MenuItem was pressed based on it's id
    case R.id.menu_us:
            menuUS();
            break;
    case R.id.menu_metric:
            menuMetric();
            break;          
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
    String preference = settings.getString("preference", string);
    if (preference.equals("us"))
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_us).setChecked(true);
    else if (preference.equals("metric"))
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_metric).setChecked(true);
    return true;
}

public void menuUS() {
    prefs = true;
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,   Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("preference", "us");
    editor.commit();
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "prefs value menuUS: " +prefs);
}

public void menuMetric() {
    prefs = false;
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("preference", "metric");
    editor.commit();
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "prefs value menuMetric: " +prefs);
}

public void calculateCylinder(View v) {
    Intent calculateCylinderUS = new Intent(this, CalculateCylinder.class);
    Intent calculateCylinderMetric = new Intent(this, CalculateCylinderMetric.class);
     Log.v(LOG_TAG, "prefs value calculateCylinder: " +prefs);
    if (prefs == true)
        startActivity(calculateCylinderUS);
    else if (prefs == false)
        startActivity(calculateCylinderMetric);
}
```